# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when opening angle bracket

Tags: editor, visual-studio-2015

as soon as I open an angle bracket in a cshtml file, Visual Studio crashes.

I deleted the .suo file but no change. I also deactivated every editor related add-in.

Comment: This also happened to me when trying to edit or add attributes to html nodes within my cshtml files in Visual Studio 2015 Community. Seems it was the same problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turned out that the asp.net and web tools beta 7 caused the problem. I also had problems loading projects what took me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465495/exception-on-opening-existing-project-after-ugrading-to-asp-net-mvc6-beta7).

Installing english langugage pack and switching VS to english helped me.